# Welcher Fall wird nach „wie (z. B.)“ verwendet?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Verlangt *wie* (im Sinne von *zum Beispiel*) einen speziellen Fall, oder wird der gleiche Fall wie beim vorangegangenen Objekt verwendet?

Was ist z. B. korrekt:

> Bedingt durch Faktoren wie [der/dem/den] Tod ist ...

Mein Gefühl sagt *dem*, aber ich bin mir nicht sicher. Oder bei:

> teilnehmen an Aktivitäten wie [Besuche/Besuchen]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Es steht der Fall des Substantivs, das näher erläutert wird:

> - "Ein Staatsoberhaupt wie der Bundespräsident genießt natürlich ebenfalls parlamentarische Immunität" (Nominativ)
> - "Der Verdauungstrakt eines Wiederkäuers wie einer Kuh ist kompliziert aufgebaut" (Genitiv)
> - "Die unbekannten Größen des Dreiecks lassen sich mit trigonometrischen Formeln wie dem Kosinussatz berechnen" (Dativ)
> - "Ein inneres Organ wie ein Herz präpariert man am besten, indem man..." (Akkusativ)

Für den Genitiv ist es allerdings üblicher, sich auf die gesamte Phrase zu beziehen, wobei Wiederholungen durch Auslassung vermieden werden: "Der Verdauungstrakt eines Wiederkäuers wie **der** [Verdauungstrakt] einer Kuh..." (damit stände der Nominativ hinter wie)

Comment: Das mit der Kuh könnte auch ein *"verkürzter Vergleichssatz"* sein, denn man würde sagen *"[,] wie [es] der einer Kuh [ist]"*.

Comment: Richtig. *Wie* und *als* bestimmen nicht den Kasus, sondern "leiten ihn weiter" (Duden Grammatik § 940). Es muss also heißen: "Bedingt durch Faktoren wie den Tod ist ..." und "teilnehmen an Aktivitäten wie Besuchen".

Comment: In den Beispielen der Frage bestimmen übrigens die Präpositionen *an* (verlangt Dativ oder Akkusativ) und *durch* (verlangt Akkusativ).

Comment: @Jakob: Ich weiß nicht - Tod ist ja nur ein Faktor. "Gezeichnet durch Krankheiten wie Pest, Cholera, Syphillis und Tripper ..." - die Arktikel kann man weglassen. Ansonsten aber Zustimmung.

Answer (score 4):

Leider trügt euch Eurer Sprachgefühl, "dem" ist ganz und gar falsch.
Nur diese Variante, der Akkusativ ist korrekt:

> "Bedingt durch Faktoren wie den Tod ist ..."

Allerdings ist das schon ein gewagter Satz, in dem der Tod als einer unter vielen Faktoren aufgezählt wird - denn was für ein Faktor kann **dann noch** zu irgendetwas beitragen (im Sinne einer Aufzählung nach "wie")?

"teilnehmen an Aktivitäten wie Besuchen" ist korrekt, weil die Präposition "an", wie übrigens die meisten Präpositionen, den Dativ verlangt und beide Nomen in diesem Fall stehen müssen.

Comment: Bzgl. gewagter Satz. Wie wär's mit: "[Irgendein Text über eine Hilfsorganisation] Obwohl man bereits vielen Menschen helfen konnte, ist ein zufriedenstellender Erfolg, bedingt durch Faktoren wie der andauernden Hungersnot, schwerwiegenden Krankheiten oder gar den Tod, nicht absehbar."

Answer (score 2):

In der Regel hängt es ja bloß von dem Verb ab. Entferne das erste Wort (und "wie"), und dann hast du deine Antwort:

> "Ich nehme an Aktivitäten wie Besuchen teil" = "Ich nehme an
>   Besuchen teil".

Answer (score -3):

Ich kann dir kein grammatikalischen Regeln nennen, aber mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir auch ganz klar Dativ.

Also:

> Bedingt durch Faktoren wie **dem** Tod ist...
>
> teilnehmen an Aktivitäten wie **Besuchen**

---

Siehe auch: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Gebrauch/Satzteil.html)

Comment: D.h. *wie* verlangt entweder Nominativ oder den Fall, den das Verb davor (bzw. genauer gesagt die Präposition dazwischen) verlangt, wie @Kevin geschrieben hat. Somit wäre (auch entgegen meinem Sprachgefühl) *dem* Tod falsch; richtig wäre entweder "durch Faktoren wie *der* Tod" oder "durch Faktoren wie *den* Tod".

Comment: Dativ ist nur im zweiten Fall richtig, denn "Aktivitäten" ist Dativ Plural - und somit muss auch *Besuch* im Dativ Plural stehen. Vgl. [Antwort von @Landei](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4081/1348).